# Connect I2P-zero GUI to remote router started with CLI

Tags: i2p, i2p-zero

Can the I2P-zero GUI connect to a distant I2P-zero router started with the CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The i2p-zero GUI is for interacting with the local / embedded router, not a remote router (if that's what you mean by "distant").